# Detect mouseup after dragging

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery UI `draggable` working on an element.

When `elementA` is being dragged, I'm removing a class from `elementB`.

I want the detect when `elementA` has stopped being dragged, and add the class back to `elementB`.

```
$('.container').draggable({

    // Output offset while dragging box
    drag: function(){

        $('.properties').removeClass('appear');

        // Detect mouseup after dragging has stopped
        // and add .appear back to .properties
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stop`:

```
$('.container').draggable({

  // Output offset while dragging box
  drag: function(){

    $('.properties').removeClass('appear');

    // Detect mouseup after dragging has stopped
    // and add .appear back to .properties
  },
  stop: function() {
    // Add your class back to elementB here.
    $('.properties').addClass('appear');
  }

});
```

Read more about `stop` and Draggable events in the jQuery UI examples: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events